# Как получить значение параметра из ссылки на javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка вида https://example.com/towers/campaigns/12345678/?ulogin=abcd&id=00000000&from=0000000000000&to=000000000000. Нужно получить из нее значения параметров ulogin и id. Написал такую функцию:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    const regex = new RegExp(`[\\?&]{0,1}\\[?${name}\\]?`);
    const results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (!results) {
      return null;
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Затем записываю результат функции в переменную, чтобы получить нужный мне параметр и потом вставить в другую ссылку

```
let login = getParameterByName("ulogin");
let id = getParameterByName("id");
```

но в итоге в значениях переменных возвращается null.

Подскажите, как мне это исправить? Есть ли другой способ получить эти значения? И почему этот не работает?

Comment: неверно составлено регулярное выражение

Comment: что именно ты хочешь сделать своим регулярным выражением?

Comment: @Grundy что такое регулярное выражение? я новичок, написал этот код через нейросеть.

Comment: `new RegExp(` вот тут ты создаешь регулярное выражение. Если ты не знаешь что это такое, то скорее всего оно вообще не заработает.

Comment: *написал этот код через нейросеть* - да... интересное нас ждет поколение разработчиков через 5 лет...

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с url, можно воспользоваться встроенным классом [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), из полученного объекта можно взять свойство [`.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) - в котором хранятся уже разобранные параметры.

Далее получить конкретный:

```js
console.log(
  new URL('https://example.com/towers/campaigns/12345678/?ulogin=abcd&id=00000000&from=0000000000000&to=000000000000').searchParams.get('ulogin')
)
```

Comment: не понимаю что я делаю не так, на сайте ваш код запускается и все прекрасно, а закидываю в vscode - возвращает null (вернее вообще не работает)

Comment: @mancelli, что конкретно и куда ты "закидываешь"? Как запускаешь?

Answer (score 0):

Для парсинга параметров из строки, можно воспользоваться [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Вот пример:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let login = urlParams.get('ulogin');
let id = urlParams.get('id');
```

---

Почему конкретно ваш код не работает правильно, я пока не выяснил. Знаю, что проблема в регулярных выражениях.

Вот код, который взят из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501690/javascript-documentation-on-getparameterbyname) с английского stackoverflow, который подозрительно похож на ваш, но зато работает):

```js
function getParameterByName( name ){
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Сравните регулярное выражение из кода выше со своим, и сможете понять где допустили ошибку.

P.s. аааа это еще и нейронка написала), тогда все понятно.

Comment: тоже не работает, возвращает пустую строку

Comment: @mancelli я опечатался. Вместо `ulogin`, написал `login`. Поправил.